# Using two ethernet connections (Internet enabled) simultaneously

Tags: internet, networking, interface

**I have searched and read** over the Internet and also on askubuntu.

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 and my question or the thing that I want to achieve is efficient use of both the connections and thus increasing my browsing and downloading speed.

I want my system to decide which packet should be routed over which interface. I want to know if this is possible.

For example, Is it possible to route alternate packets over the two interfaces ?

Please let me know any Internet resource or If I would have to insert any code into the network drivers etc. ?

Comment: huh?  what speed are you connected to the internet? If you are connected less than the capacity of your network interface why do you think your download speed will increase?  Its not physically possible - what I think you are referring to is the term "load balancing".

Comment: I mean to say virtual increase in the browsing speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the explanation for a solution for this is very long I will point to the sites that have some pretty extensive knowledge about it and are working on projects that can help with this:

- Network Load Balancing - http://lnlb.sourceforge.net/
- IPTables with Multiple Connections - http://linux-ip.net/html/adv-multi-internet.html

Firewall Managers like **Shorewall** are known to help in scenarios like this although they need a bit of setting them up for this.

In most cases as you have searched over the internet you noticed one of two things:

- Network Load Balancing is easier to achieve than bonding. you are not aggregating the internet connection, only using each one separately.
- Bonding is easier to achieve with hardware made for that, like special switches or routers.

In this last case, the best I have seen (not tested) is this: http://www.internetloadbalancers.com/ which offers hardware that can solve your problems and make it zero conf.

If the links provided and solutions using iptables and firewalls do not work, you can always count on a hardware device that does it easier.